# Connection Reset by peer + Ruby + httparty +api

Tags: ruby, openssl, httparty

I am getting data from an api (which supports SSLv3 and TLS 1.0) via a ruby interface. Some of the calls which loads large amount of data throws the below error.

Connection reset by peer
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/openssl/buffering.rb:318:in `syswrite'

Can we fix it either in client side or service side?

Comment: Please debug more.  There's not enough information here.  What happens when you don't use SSL?  What happens when you use another HTTP library like Faraday or the rest-client gem (if your API is rest)?  What does `curl` do?